# How do I programmatically refund using Authorize.net in PHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, payment-gateway, authorize.net

I am using Authorize.net payment module(AIM) with my cakephp framework. Payment functionality is working fine. Now i need to do a **REFUND Functionality** with my framework. I checked their Api's but i could not get any thing. According to their API guide the following parameters are needed If I passed they asking exp date too. In my database we are storing only last 4 digits of CC. any way i try to pass all the 16 digits but the response not proper. Just i need a sample PHP code for Authorize.net Refund.

> **x_type=CREDIT**
>
> **x_trans_id=Transaction ID here**
>
> **x_card_num=Full credit card number or last four digits only here**

I am passing following parameters

```
        "x_type"                => 'CREDIT',

        "x_trans_id"            => $x_trans_id,

        "x_card_num"            => '4111111111111111',

       "x_exp_date"            => '' ,

        "x_amount"                => $x_amount,

        'x_test_request' => TRUE
```

Now  I getting the following error message :

> (TESTMODE) A valid referenced transaction ID is required.

Comment: The docs say that an expiration date is *not* required. Make sure you include the minimum required fields. Can you post what you've tried and the error returned by Authorize? It may be that you just need to include the `x_exp_date` key but leave it blank.

Comment: i updated the question can u please check that jere

Comment: It all looks good to me. You are just missing a valid transaction, like the error says. Probably because you are in test mode. I added the answer since it answers this question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though an expiration date is not *required*, it seems that you still need to pass the key because it's in the list of required Authorize.net keys. Just pass `x_exp_date => ''` and you should be good!